# How can I see the text that I'm typing in editText window in alertDialog?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code for an `AlertDialog` window in which I want the user to input a number(that I'm storing in int `m_Text`). I have 2 problems: I can't see the numbers that I'm typing and if I press enter without any numbers it will crash. How can I solve them ? (the method `pressMe()` is executed when I press a button)

```
public void pressMe(){
       final EditText input = new EditText(this);
       input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlert.setMessage("Enter number:")
                .setView(input)
                .setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        m_Text = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                        Log.d(TAG," Number :  "+m_Text");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                })
                .setTitle("Test")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .create();
        myAlert.show();
    }
```

Comment: I think it would be better to make a dialog activity, and then the EditText would be in the xml layout file rather than created in code, and everything would work normally.

Comment: `I can't see the numbers that I'm typing`. What do you mean by that? Do you mean: `while typing'I cant see the digits that i type`.

Comment: what kind of instance is m_Text? Integer? What do you want to do with this?

Comment: @greenapps yes, that's what I meant. Konrad It's an int, I said that in the post. I want to store the value entered in the text field in it

Comment: Try without `input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer why your application is crashed is here:

```
Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

When input text is empty you try to parse `""` on Integer and you get `NumberFormatException`.

you have to handle this situation for example like in code below:

```
final String str = input.getText().toString().trim();
m_Text = str.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(str);
```

or

```
final String str = input.getText().toString().trim();
if(str.length() != 0){
     m_Text = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

I don't understand your first problem. If you explain it to me, I help you.

**Update** 
When I tried your code I have result like below:

[image]

Comment: In my opinion the better way is checking that input is not empty. Parsing operation, when text is empty, is redundant. We should prevent exception.

Comment: We know that user always insert number because there is used `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` so there is no other possibilities to get exception

Comment: Oops, you're correct. I just noticed the OP has the input type restricted to numbers. Good call. Cheers!

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak My first problem: I can't see the number that I'm typing when I'm typing them. It's like they are set to password something. I will try now what you said :D

Comment: @Daniel sorry but when I tried reproduce your issue with your code I have this solution. Look on my post - everything works fine - I think so.

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak ... I can see. I have no idea why I can't see when I'm typing. Thank you. I'll try again when I get home

Answer (score 0):

Read this document
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

if you want to use any types of dialog in your application.

1)Create a class that will extend DialogFragment class.

2)Overide onCreateDialog() method and inside that write your code for both Positive button and negative button

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

3)Call that Fragment from HostActivity using this code

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new YourFragmentClass();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
```

if you want a CustomLayout then

1)create a XML file in res->customLayout.xml and inside that place the view you want(In your case draw a Single EditText on that layout),do not add Button for Positive or Negative Button they are already add by DialogFragment.

2)Inside onCreateDialog() of dialogFragment do something like this

```
// Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    final EditText et_text=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextId);

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null))

           // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.send, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                   String mob=et_text.getText().toString();

                    //Do What you want to do with EditText

           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   //Coding for Negative Button Here
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();

}
```

you can Pass EventBack to Hosting Activity.
Read reference document

Hope this will help you